# odoo-10 sequence increment when click on Cancel button

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

I develop a Odoo module for add sequence to employee, work perfectly.

I do click to create button and appear the sequence for these employee, but id canceled the create the sequence increment anyway

```
class nhr(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'hr.employee'
    nhr = fields.Char(string='Nº de contacto', index=True, readonly=True, required=True,
        default=lambda self: self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('nhr.seq'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It increases sequence number because you have set logic in default value at field declaration.

To avoid such issues, we need to set logic in *create()* method.

Try with following code:

```
nhr = fields.Char(string='Nº de contacto', index=True, readonly=True)

@api.model
def create(self, vals):

    vals['nhr'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('nhr.seq')

    return super(nhr, self).create(vals)
```

NOTE:

Restart Odoo server and upgrade your custom module.

Answer (score 0):

There are case where @Odedra's solution won't work, when a rollback of the transaction creating the nhr record. In this case the underlying sequence implementation will still be incremented.

You can use the 'gapless' implementation of sequences (it's a field on the `ir.sequence` model) to ensure that all numbers are consecutive. However this comes at a huge cost as the implementation works with a global lock which will serialize the creation of your records.

Comment: (odoo 10)

For gapless implementation:

<field name="implementation">no_gap<field>